# tilda selector css, label button not working for responsive menu

Tags: html, css, responsive

My problem is i am trying to create responsive menu, every thing work fine, after that, What i did i hide my menu and display a button when screen is less than certain size, which is fine my button show up, but after checking on the box my menu does not show up,
I am trying to use check box to display the menu, means if check box is checked than only display the menu if screen is less than 600px, please read the media query last part, as that's the problem, rest of the code work. 
please read the comment in the css code,

and i think the problem is in the last style of css, so please check that first, and you don't have to read the whole code, i leave the comment in the code to tell you which part is not working,

**Html code**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <label for="show-menu" class="show-menu">Show Menu</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="show-menu">
    <nav>

            <ul class="flex-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Plans</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
            </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

**Css code**

```
*{margin:0; padding:0;}

.wrapper  { 
    color:white;
    font-family:Helvetica;
}
nav{background:black}
/*making the button and checkbox invisible
This work fine, 
I try to display it in media query, work fine
it showed up when screen is less than 600px
*/
.show-menu {
    display:none;

}
input[type=checkbox]{
    display:none;
}

/*styling nav bar*/

.flex-nav{
    display:flex;
    list-style-type:none;
}

.flex-nav li{
    flex:1;
    text-align:center;
}

.flex-nav li a {
    display:block;
    padding:20px 0;
    text-decoration:none;
}


/*media query*/
@media screen and (max-width:600px){
    /*displaying the button work fine, also
    read the first comment */
    .show-menu{
    background:#1a1a1a;
    cursor:pointer;
    padding:20px 0;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    }

    /*saying dont display class flex-nav work fine*/
    .flex-nav{
        display:none;
    }
    /*now saying display flex-nav children if button is 
    click. does not work driving my tiny brain nuts*/
    input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .flex-nav
    {
        display:block;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That last CSS selector (in the media query) should be

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked + nav > .flex-nav {
  display:block;
}
```

Reason: `input` and `.flex-nav` are NOT siblings. `.flex-nav` is a child of `nav`, which is a sibling of `input`, in fact `.flex-nav` directly follows `nav`, therefore the `+`

Comment: thanks it work, i don't fully understand why, but i am reading your explanation again, may be i will thanks again

Comment: i understand it fully now, i went back and check my code, i though they were sibiling, but they are not silly mistake, thanks for the help, i try to accept the answer but it saying, you got the answer to soon so you should suffer a bit more before accepting it.